# Simplify $\frac{\sin t - \cos t}{\sin t + \cos t}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

$$\frac{\sin t - \cos t}{\sin t + \cos t}$$

I am to simplify this into $$\tan(t - \frac{\pi}{4})$$

I'm not sure how to carry on, though. Multiplying numerator and denominator by denominator (or numerator) doesn't get me anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step-by-step

$$ \dfrac{\sin t - \cos t}{\sin t + \cos t}$$

$$= \dfrac{\dfrac{\sin t}{\cos t} - \dfrac{\cos t}{\cos t}}{\dfrac{\sin t}{\cos t} + \dfrac{\cos t}{\cos t}}$$

$$= \dfrac{\tan t - 1}{\tan t + 1}$$

$$= \dfrac{\tan t - 1}{1 + \tan t \color{blue}{\cdot 1}}$$

Substitute $\color{blue}{\tan \frac{\pi}{4} = 1}$

$$= \dfrac{\tan t - \tan \frac{\pi}{4}}{1 + \tan t \color{blue}{\tan \frac{\pi}{4}}}$$

$$= \tan (t - \frac{\pi}{4})$$

We have used the formula

$$ \tan(A-B) = \dfrac{\tan A - \tan B}{1 + \tan A \tan B} $$

Answer (score 3):

You know that you already need to use an angle addition identity, because the desired result $\tan (t - \pi/4)$ contains the difference of two angles.

So, which such identities do you know?  Specifically, do you know of the tangent angle addition identity $$\tan (a - b) = \frac{\sin (a - b)}{\cos (a - b)} = \frac{\sin a \cos b - \cos a \sin b}{\cos a \cos b + \sin a \sin b}?$$  Now, what happens if we let $a = t$ and $b = \pi/4$?

Comment: okay, but cos b and sin b will not be equal to 1, so how does the equality maintain when we only have $\frac{\sin t - \cos t}{\sin t + \cos t}$?

Comment: @user841356 When $b = \pi/4$, we have $$\sin b = \cos b = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}.$$

Comment: Right. So when we expand $\frac{sin(a-b)}{cos(a-b)}$, we get the full form up in the post. Then we substitute t for a and $\frac{\pi}{4}$ for b. now cos b and sin b are $\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$, right? For the original equation (the one we start out with -- $\frac{sint - cost}{sint + cost}$) to equal this one, wouldn't cosb and sinb have to equal 1?

Comment: @user841356 Are the following expressions equal?  $$\frac{x / \sqrt{2}}{y / \sqrt{2}} \overset{?}{=} \frac{x}{y}$$

Comment: Got it. We could factor out the $\frac{1}{\sqrt4}$ and cancel them. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$\frac{\sin t - \cos t}{\sin t + \cos t} = \frac{\sqrt{2}\sin(t - \frac{\pi}{4})}{\sqrt{2}\sin(t + \frac{\pi}{4})} =  \frac{\sqrt{2}\sin(t - \frac{\pi}{4})}{\sqrt{2}\cos(t - \frac{\pi}{4})} = \tan(t- \frac{\pi}{4})$$